# Multiple quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Can anybody translate the following expression and explain why it's true?

$$\forall x \in I : \exists y \in N : y = x^2$$

where $I$ - set of integers, $N$ - set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct translation first:

> for each integer $x$ there is a natural number $y$ such that $y=x^2$.

That’s probably a little more intelligible if we rearrange it a bit: all it’s saying is that

> the square of any integer is a natural number.

And this is true. First, the product of two integers is an integer, so in particular every square of an integer is an integer. Moreover, if $x$ is any real number we know that $x^2\ge 0$, so every square of an integer is non-negative. Put the two together, and we have that the square of an integer is always a non-negative integer, i.e., a natural number.